# Calculating Overtime for multiple jobs per day using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this example, https://rickosborne.org/blog/2006/01/calculating-overtime-with-pure-sql/, I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    Employee,
    In_Day,
    Job_Code2,
    Job_Code,
    CASE
        WHEN (HoursBefore < 40.0)
        AND (HoursAfter > 40.0)
        THEN
            /* straddler */
            CASE
                WHEN p.i = 0
                THEN Hours + (40.0 - HoursAfter)
                ELSE HoursAfter - 40.0
            END
            /* hours adjustment */
        ELSE Hours
            /* no adjustment */
    END AS Hours,
    CASE
        WHEN (HoursBefore < 40.0)
        AND (HoursAfter > 40.0)
        THEN
            CASE
                WHEN p.i = 0
                THEN 1.0
                ELSE 1.5
            END
            /* straddlers */
        WHEN HoursBefore >= 40.0
        THEN 1.5
            /* non-straddlers after 40 hours */
        ELSE 1
            /* non-straddlers before 40 hours */
    END AS Rate,
    HoursBefore,
    HoursAfter
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.Employee,
            a.In_Day,
            a.Job_Code2,
            a.Job_Code,
            COALESCE(SUM(b.Hours),0) AS HoursBefore,
            a.Hours,
            COALESCE(SUM(b.Hours),0) + a.Hours AS HoursAfter
        FROM
            v_TimeSheet a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            v_TimeSheet b
        ON
            (
                a.Employee = b.Employee)
        AND (
                b.In_Day < a.In_Day)

        GROUP BY
            a.Employee,
            a.In_Day,
            a.Job_Code,
            a.Hours ) AS c

INNER JOIN
    Pivot p
ON
    (
        i <
        CASE
            WHEN (HoursBefore < 40.0)
            AND (HoursAfter > 40.0)
            THEN 2
            ELSE 1
        END)
ORDER BY
    Employee,
    In_Day,
    Job_Code;
```

I have come across an issue while calculating hours per day.  The results work for 90% of the employees on the table, however it doesnt seem to be adding up the hours by row.

This is an example output of what it does currently (modified slightly for my cause):

```
Employee    In_Day  Job_Code2   Job_Code    Hours   Rate    HoursBefore HoursAfter
EMPLOYEE 1  3/16/2015   13041   90100       5       1       0           5
EMPLOYEE 1  3/16/2015   13041   90400       5       1       0           5
EMPLOYEE 1  3/17/2015   13041   90100       4       1       10          14
EMPLOYEE 1  3/17/2015   13041   90400       2       1       10          12
EMPLOYEE 1  3/17/2015   13041   90500       2.5     1       10          12.5
EMPLOYEE 1  3/17/2015   13041   300100      2.5     1       10          12.5
EMPLOYEE 1  3/18/2015   13041   90100       4       1       21          25
EMPLOYEE 1  3/18/2015   13041   90400       3       1       21          24
EMPLOYEE 1  3/18/2015   13041   90500       4       1       21          25
EMPLOYEE 1  3/19/2015   13041   90100       2       1       32          34
EMPLOYEE 1  3/19/2015   13041   90400       2       1       32          34
EMPLOYEE 1  3/19/2015   13041   90500       4       1       32          36
EMPLOYEE 1  3/19/2015   13041   300100      3       1       32          35
EMPLOYEE 1  3/20/2015   13041   90100       2       1.5     43          45
EMPLOYEE 1  3/20/2015   13041   90400       4       1.5     43          47
EMPLOYEE 1  3/20/2015   13041   90500       4       1.5     43          47
EMPLOYEE 1  3/21/2015   13041   90100       3       1.5     53          56
EMPLOYEE 1  3/21/2015   13041   90400       3       1.5     53          56
EMPLOYEE 1  3/21/2015   13041   90500       2       1.5     53          55
EMPLOYEE 1  3/21/2015   13041   300100      2       1.5     53          55
EMPLOYEE 2  3/16/2015   14071   100A19      4.5     1       0           4.5
EMPLOYEE 2  3/16/2015   14071   100A23      5       1       0           5
EMPLOYEE 2  3/17/2015   14071   100A19      2.5     1       9.5         12
EMPLOYEE 2  3/17/2015   14071   100A23      7       1       9.5         16.5
EMPLOYEE 2  3/18/2015   14071   100A19      3       1       19          22
EMPLOYEE 2  3/18/2015   14071   100A24      5.5     1       19          24.5
EMPLOYEE 2  3/20/2015   14071   100A24      9.5     1       27.5        37
EMPLOYEE 2  3/21/2015   14071   100A24      3       1       37          46.5
EMPLOYEE 2  3/21/2015   14071   100A24      6.5     1.5     37          46.5
```

With EMPLOYEE 2, everything is calculate correctly by splitting the 3/21 record into 2 and having only 6.5 hours of overtime.  However, on EMPLOYEE 1, he is short 3 hours of overtime because of 3/19 Job_Code 300100 is calculated as regular time instead of overtime.

I have tried many different ways to group by to see if I can get the result I need.

Does anyone have a suggestion to correct this or maybe have an alternative solution?

Comment: I imagine it has to do with your job codes, and that you can have more than one record in a given day.  If you removed the job codes and/or summed your a.hours (remove it from the group by) you should get the correct results.

Comment: I need the job codes though so I can assign overtime to the correct "sub" job.

Comment: OK. Then try adding this to your query where it says `b.In_Day < a.In_Day` put `(b.In_Day < a.In_Day or (b.In_Day = b.In_Day and b.job_code < a.job_code))`

Comment: That gives an extra 4 hours of overtime.

Example - http://i.imgur.com/bbma8Xj.png

Comment: Hmmm....  The numbers seem off.  Why does 3/23 start off with 9.  Then you add 6 and get 15 which is the hours before of the next which is correct.  Plus 4 makes 19 which should be the hours before of the 3/24 but somehow that shows an hours before of 15.  I would work with just the subquery until you get the right values, but it's there where you need your incrementing to work